# Covariance of two Pareto distributed random variables

Tags: distribution, covariance

How can we compute covariance of two Pareto distributed random variables.
cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y). Here, X is pareto distributed with parameters(a,b) and Y has parameters (c,d). X and Y are not independent

Comment: Isn't it equal to 0? If you have two independent Pareto then E(XY)=E(X)E(Y), and  cov(X,Y)=0

Comment: Yes..Ok I update the question...that they are not independent

Comment: Well, that's good to hear, but you have to provide us with nature of dependence - joint PDF, or copula, or ...